# Load Tab delimited file in into jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

my task is load the tab delimited file  into psql database via jdbc code. I used PreparedStatement to execute the query.  but I'm not able to load the data to the database ,I got exception like this" INSERT has more expressions than target columns".here I have attached my code  please help me out.

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class process {
    static Connection connection = null;

    public static void instertable(String line, Connection connection) {
        String values[] = null;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        int i = 0;
        try {

            pst = connection.prepareStatement("insert into  tablename values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            values = line.split("\t");
            System.out.println("len" + values.length);
            for (i = 0; i <= values.length; i++) {

                System.out.println(values[i]);
                pst.setString(i + 1, values[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("ii " + i);
            System.out.println("pst " + pst);

            pst.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("load data database");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("load error:" + ex.getMessage());

        }


    }

    public static void readfile(String FileName, Connection connection) {
        BufferedReader bufferedreader = null;
        String line = null;
        try {

            bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName));
            while ((line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {

                //  System.out.println(line);
                instertable(line, connection);
            }


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.getMessage();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String FileName = "i.txt";
        //String LoadOutput=args[3];

        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/dbname", "username",
                    "password");
            readfile(FileName, connection);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception message : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: There are many possible exceptions that can be thrown when talking to a database.  Please edit your question to include the full details of the exception that your code is throwing.  It will be very difficult for anyone to help you without this information.

Comment: I got exception like this: INSERT has more expressions than target columns

Comment: please add the schema definition of your Table: `Create table xy...`

Answer (score 2):

There's an error here:

```
for (i = 0; i <= values.length; i++) {
```

`<=` should be `<`: when `i` is `values.length`, `values[i]` will cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` to be thrown.  You are iterating over the loop one time too many.

When an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown, the exception message may contain only the errant index.  This would explain why you are getting `load error: 32` as your own message.

Incidentally, you are partially a victim of your own poor error-handling here:

```
    catch (Exception ex) {
         System.out.println("load error:"+ex.getMessage());
    }
```

You're catching `Exception`, which is very general, and only displaying the error message.
Instead, I would recommend catching `SQLException` (which generally does have helpful error messages) instead of `Exception`.

Lastly, you should also be closing the `PreparedStatement`.  Do this in a `finally` block:

```
    finally {
        if (pst != null) {
            try {
                pst.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Error closing prepared statement: " + e.getMessage());
            } 
        }
    }
```

The next problem, as evidenced by your edited comment, is here:

```
    pst = connection.prepareStatement("insert into  tablename values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

The message you are getting suggests that your table has fewer than 32 columns, so it can't insert all of the data.  I would recommend adding the column names to the `INSERT` statement:

```
    pst = connection.prepareStatement("insert into tablename (column1, column2, ..., column32) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

By specifying the column names, you fix the order of the columns, and also ensure that if any columns are added to the table in the future you don't suddenly get an error message.

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear: there are more ? than columns in table tablename. I would recommend you to always specify the column list in an insert statement: you can also control the order of the columns that way.